# Receive SIGTERM on logstash startup version 7.1.1

Tags: kubernetes, logstash, kubernetes-helm

I am trying to use logstash to send data from kafka to s3 via logstash, and I am getting an SIGTERM in the logstash process with no apparent error messages.

I am using the following helm template override.yaml file.

```
# overrides stable/logstash helm templates
inputs:
  main: |-
    input {
      kafka{
        bootstrap_servers =>  "kafka.system.svc.cluster.local:9092"
        group_id => "kafka-s3"
        topics => "device,message"
        consumer_threads => 3
        codec => json { charset => "UTF-8" }
        decorate_events => true
      }
    }

# time_file default = 15 minutes
# size_file default = 5242880 bytes
outputs:
  main: |-
    output {
      s3 {
        codec => "json"
        prefix => "kafka/%{+YYYY}/%{+MM}/%{+dd}/%{+HH}-%{+mm}"
        time_file => 5
        size_file => 5242880
        region => "ap-northeast-1"
        bucket => "logging"
        canned_acl => "private"
      }
    }

podAnnotations: {
  iam.amazonaws.com/role: kafka-s3-rules
  }

image:
  tag: 7.1.1
```

my AWS IAM role should be attached to the container via iam2kube.  The role itself allows all actions on S3.

My S3 bucket has a policy as follows:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "LoggingBucketPolicy",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1554291237763",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "636082426924"
            },
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::logging/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

The logs for the container are as follows.

```
2019/06/13 10:31:15 Setting 'path.config' from environment.
2019/06/13 10:31:15 Setting 'queue.max_bytes' from environment.
2019/06/13 10:31:15 Setting 'queue.drain' from environment.
2019/06/13 10:31:15 Setting 'http.port' from environment.
2019/06/13 10:31:15 Setting 'http.host' from environment.
2019/06/13 10:31:15 Setting 'path.data' from environment.
2019/06/13 10:31:15 Setting 'queue.checkpoint.writes' from environment.
2019/06/13 10:31:15 Setting 'queue.type' from environment.
2019/06/13 10:31:15 Setting 'config.reload.automatic' from environment.
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: If the number of processors is expected to increase from one, then you should configure the number of parallel GC threads appropriately using -XX:ParallelGCThreads=N
Sending Logstash logs to /usr/share/logstash/logs which is now configured via log4j2.properties
[2019-06-13T10:31:38,061][WARN ][logstash.config.source.multilocal] Ignoring the 'pipelines.yml' file because modules or command line options are specified
[2019-06-13T10:31:38,078][INFO ][logstash.runner          ] Starting Logstash {"logstash.version"=>"7.1.1"}
[2019-06-13T10:32:02,882][WARN ][logstash.runner          ] SIGTERM received. Shutting down.
```

Is there anyway to get more detailed logs, or does anyone know what I am dealing with?
I greatly appriciate any help or advice! :no_mouth:

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Problem:

Looking at the pod details for logstash, I was able to identify the issue.. I an entry similar to the following.

```
I0414 19:41:24.402257    3338 prober.go:104] Liveness probe for "mypod:mycontainer" failed (failure): Get http://10.168.0.3:80/: dial tcp 10.168.0.3:80: connection refused
```

It specified a "connection refused" for liveness probe, and after 50~60 seconds of uptime restarted the pod.

## Cause:

looking at the liveness probe in the helm chart `Values.yaml` it shows the following settings.

```
...

livenessProbe:
  httpGet:
    path: /
    port: monitor
initialDelaySeconds: 20
# periodSeconds: 30
# timeoutSeconds: 30
# failureThreshold: 6
# successThreshold: 1

...
```

Only `InitialDelaySeconds` is set, so the others should be Kubernetes defaults as shown [**here**](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-probes/#configure-probes) to the following.

```
# periodSeconds: 10
# timeoutSeconds: 1
# failureThreshold: 1
# successThreshold: 3
```

This indicates the following give or take a few seconds:

```
+------+-----------------------------+
| Time |            Event            |
+------+-----------------------------+
| 0s   | Container created           |
| 20s  | First liveness probe        |
| 21s  | First liveness probe fails  |
| 31s  | Second liveness probe       |
| 32s  | Second liveness probe fails |
| 42s  | Third liveness probe        |
| 43s  | Third liveness probe fails  |
| 44s  | Send SIGTERM to application |
+------+-----------------------------+
```

## Solution:

After some troubleshooting to find the correct `InitialDelaySeconds` value, I put the following into my `override.yaml` file to fix the issue.

```
livenessProbe:
  initialDelaySeconds: 90
```

It seems that depending on the plugins being used, Logstash may not respond to HTTP requests for upwards of 100s.

Comment: perfect explanation and solution! worked for me for the same issue